# Save and restore state in SimpleSAMLphp authentication module

Tags: php, simplesamlphp, idp

I'm developing an authentication module for SimpleSAMLphp. Since as part of the authentication flow I have to show a QR code to the user, according to [SimpleSAMLphp's docs](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-authsource.html) I have to first save the current state, then redirect the user to another page. After the user scanned the QR code, I should be abe to restore the previous state and complete the authentication. The problem I'm facing is that SimpleSAMLphp throws an exception when I try to restore the state.
Here is my module's authenticate() function:

```
public function authenticate(array &$state): void
{
    assert(is_array($state));
    $id=\SimpleSAML\Auth\State::saveState($state, 'irmaIdentityProvider:beforeRedirect');
    $url = \SimpleSAML\Module::getModuleURL('irmaidentity/irmaLoginPage.php');
    $httpUtils = new \SimpleSAML\Utils\HTTP();
    $httpUtils->redirectTrustedURL($url, array('authStateId' => $id));
}
```

In the module's class, I also have a callback function that is called
by the page displaying the QR code to pass back the disclosed attribute and the state id.
It takes care of restoring the state and completing the authentication
process:

```
public static function attributeCallback($attribute, $authStateId)
{
    /* Retrieve the authentication state. */
    $state = \SimpleSAML\Auth\State::loadState($authStateId, 'irmaIdentityProvider:beforeRedirect');
    $attributeArray = array("participantId"=>$attribute);
    $state['Attributes'] = SimpleSAML\Utils\Attributes::normalizeAttributesArray($attributeArray);
    \SimpleSAML\Auth\Source::completeAuth($state);
}
```

The login page (the one I'm redirecting to to show the QR code) performs the actual authentication and at the end calls my callback function like this:

```
SimpleSAML\Module\irmaidentity\Auth\Source\irmaIdentityProvider::attributeCallback($disclosed, $_GET['authStateId']);
```

It all goes well up to the point where the callback is invoked, at that point, I get the following error:

```
SimpleSAML\Error\Error: UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION
Backtrace:
2 public/_include.php:28 (SimpleSAML_exception_handler)
1 vendor/symfony/error-handler/ErrorHandler.php:607 (Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler::handleException)
0 [builtin] (N/A)
Caused by: SimpleSAML\Error\Exception: Cannot load PHP session with a specific ID.
Backtrace:
7 src/SimpleSAML/SessionHandlerPHP.php:237 (SimpleSAML\SessionHandlerPHP::loadSession)
6 src/SimpleSAML/Session.php:346 (SimpleSAML\Session::getSession)
5 src/SimpleSAML/Session.php:260 (SimpleSAML\Session::getSessionFromRequest)
4 src/SimpleSAML/Auth/State.php:271 (SimpleSAML\Auth\State::loadState)
3 /simplesamlphp-module-irmaidentity/src/Auth/Source/irmaIdentityProvider.php:44 (SimpleSAML\Module\irmaidentity\Auth\Source\irmaIdentityProvider::attributeCallback)
2 /simplesamlphp-module-irmaidentity/public/irmaLoginPage.php:115 (require)
1 src/SimpleSAML/Module.php:302 (SimpleSAML\Module::process)
0 public/module.php:14 (N/A)
```

I checked with var_dump() the state id that is returned by saveState before the redirect and the one that I get in the login page inside $_GET['authStateId'] and they seem to be the same (or at least to have the same format, I checked the two values over two different runs).
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for your help,

GTP

Comment: Maybe related to this: https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/issues/1262 Are you sending output before calling these methods? (i.e. echo, var_dump, etc.)

Comment: @JensV yes, I'm calling `echo` in the login page, because I have to generate a page containing a QR code and then show it to the user. How can I avoid that?